# Rails mailer logo. url_for vs. attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, mailer

I'm implementing a feature with mailer in Rails 4.
I managed to display the logo by using inline attachment, on the email that the user receives. It's working well but my supervisor asked me to try to find another way. This was his question:

---

Is it necessary to attach the logo? instead of using attachments, maybe url_for?
Using url_for gives the absolute path of the image. This way, the image could be hosted in our website, while being used in the email.

--

I'm trying to find a answer but I can't find it. Also the only way that I can make it to work is by using inline attachment.

Comment: You could just use the `image_tag` and load the image from your web server.

Comment: On the view, I tried:
  = image_tag("logo.jpg")
But it only displays a broken image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `url_for` or `xxx_url` helpers in mails, you must do some configuration in the files under `config/environments/`, for example

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'www.example.org', protocol: 'https'}
```

To use `image_url` or `asset_url` in mail templates, you also need to add

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'https://www.example.org'
```

By the way, inline attachments are attachments, and they do increase the size of mails, but can be displayed without the recipient's permission.

On the other hand, the images referenced by `url_for` or some sort are only URL's thus reduces the mails' size, but the MUA's have to send a separate request to download the image, and they can't do this without the permission of the recipients. If the recipient refuses to download, he will see an ugly broken image icon.

Comment: I have inside my config/environments/development.rb:
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
Would that work?
How would you write the url_for, inside the view of the mailer in order to display an image inside your assets?

Comment: If your image is a static file under `/public`, then just `root_url + '/path/to/your.jpg'`. If the image is under `app/assets`, then use `image_url('your.jpg')`

Comment: Thanks Aetherus.
My image is in app/assets/images/logo.jpg
#######
I added this to my view(Haml):           
%img(src= "#{root_url}app/assets/images/logo.jpg")
#######

And this is what I have in my config/environments/development.rb: config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 } 
#########
The email still displays a broken image and when I inspect the image this is what I get:
<img src="http://localhost:3000/app/assets/images/logo.jpg">

Comment: Use `image_url('logo.jpg')`. By the way, all the files in `app/assets` and subfolders will eventually go into `public/assets`, and a MD5 digest of the file will be added into the file names, in order to expire the cache of the old files. `image_url` takes that digest into account.

Comment: using image_url('logo.jpg') I get this:

/assets/logo-214af1e6d7e5b68f14fbe7837bbea91cce55e9076926b51f2a0ff499bc2bab10.jpg
####
I tried  =image_tag("logo"), but its the same

Comment: Add `config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'localhost:3000'` to your `config/environments/development.rb`